# How do I create a fully dynamic nested vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I need to create a vector (primary), each node having a another vector member (secondary). Both the primary and secondary vectors must be dynamically sized. I have been playing with this for a while and have come up with a few "almost there" solutions (like the one below), but I can't quite get any of them to work.

I need to be able to add to the primary vector at any time (not just at the time of creation) by doing something like `primary.push_back(primary_node)`. Additionally, I need to be able to target any one of those nodes at any time (not just at the time of creation) with an iterator and add to the vector it points to. Example: `primary.begin()->node_head.push_back(secondary_node)`. Here is a visualization of what I'm describing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5v8j.png

Again, at any point I need to be able to add to the primary (black) vector, or any one of the secondary (red) vectors. And I need to be able to select the red vectors via the black nodes.

Relevant code:

```
struct secondaryNode
{
    char *name;
    secondaryNode *next;
};

struct primaryNode
{
    char* typeName;
    std::vector<secondaryNode> *node_head; //pointer to secondary vector
};

//global primary vector
std::vector<primaryNode> primary_list;

void main() {
    struct primaryNode* primary_temp;
    primary_temp = ALLOC(struct primaryNode);
    primary_temp->typeName = strdup("primary temp");

    //initialize secondary vector
    std::vector<secondaryNode> *secondary_list = new std::vector<secondaryNode>;
    primary_temp->node_head = secondary_list;

    //first secondary node
    struct secondaryNode* foo;
    foo = ALLOC(struct secondaryNode);
    foo->name = strdup("\nfoo");
    secondary_list->push_back(*foo);

    primary_list.push_back(*primary_temp); //push primary node after giving it a secondary node

    printf("\n%d", secondary_list->size()); //outputs 1
    printf("%s", secondary_list->begin()->name); //outputs "foo"
    printf("%s", primary_list.begin()->node_head->begin()->name); //outputs "foo"

    //second secondary node
    struct secondaryNode* bar;
    bar = ALLOC(struct secondaryNode);
    bar->name = strdup("\nbar");
    secondary_list->push_back(*bar);

    printf("\n%d", secondary_list->size()); //outputs 2
    printf("\n%s", secondary_list->end()->name); //outputs NULL
    printf("\n%s", primary_list.begin()->node_head->end()->name); //outputs NULL
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
1
foo
foo
2
(null)
(null)
```

Comment: Do you want to keep `secondaryNode`s in a `vector` or a linked list? Why do you need `secondaryNode::next`?

Comment: Sorry I don't need it in there. That was from a different attempt and I forgot to remove that bit. That bit of code is actually what I'm trying to avoid (having nested linked lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your confusion comes from using pointers all over the place. In C++ you don't really have to use them often. This code may be rewritten without any pointers:

```
struct secondaryNode
{
    std::string name;
};

struct primaryNode
{
    std::string typeName;
    std::vector<secondaryNode> secondaryNodes;
};

//global primary vector
std::vector<primaryNode> primary_list;

int main() {
    primaryNode primary_temp;
    primary_temp.secondaryNodes.push_back(secondaryNode{"\nfoo"});

    primary_list.push_back(primary_temp); //push primary node after giving it a secondary node

    std::cout << primary_list[0].secondaryNodes.size() << std::endl; //outputs 1
    std::cout << primary_list[0].secondaryNodes[0].name << std::endl; //outputs "foo"

    //second secondary node
    primary_list[0].secondaryNodes.push_back(secondaryNode{"\nbar"});

    std::cout << primary_list[0].secondaryNodes.size() << std::endl; //outputs 2
    std::cout << primary_list[0].secondaryNodes[0].name << std::endl; //outputs "foo"
    std::cout << primary_list[0].secondaryNodes[1].name << std::endl; //outputs "bar"
}
```

Another error in your code is this:

```
secondary_list->end()->name
```

`end()` is an iterator to next element past end of the vector, and so dereferencing it is undefined behavior, that's why you see NULLs there.

Comment: I just tried this out and it works. Thank you! I spent forever on that.